# Unit Testing an Html Helper with AutoFixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, model-view-controller, autofixture

I'm attempting to Unit Test an Html Helper using AutoFixture. Below is my SUT

```
public static MvcHtmlString SampleTable(this HtmlHelper helper,
    SampleModel model, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    if (helper == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("helper");
    }
    if (model == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
    }

    TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("table");
    tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    tagBuilder.GenerateId(helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[Keys.SomeKey].ToString());
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

As you can see it just returns an MVC Html string with table tags and Id attached to it. (See below Unit Test result for an example)

Unit Test with AutoFixture:

```
[Fact]
public void SampleTableHtmlHelper_WhenKeyExistWithinHttpContext_ReturnsExpectedHtml()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    //Arrange
    fixture.Inject<HttpContextBase>(new FakeHttpContext());
    var httpContext = fixture.CreateAnonymous<HttpContextBase>();
    fixture.Inject<ViewContext>(new ViewContext());
    var vc = fixture.CreateAnonymous<ViewContext>();

    vc.HttpContext = httpContext;
    vc.HttpContext.Items.Add(Keys.SomeKey, "foo");

    fixture.Inject<IViewDataContainer>(new FakeViewDataContainer());
    var htmlHelper = fixture.CreateAnonymous<HtmlHelper>();
    var sampleModel = fixture.CreateAnonymous<SampleModel>();

    //Act
    var result = SampleHelpers.SampleTable(htmlHelper, sampleModel, null).ToString();

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal("<table id=\"foo\"></table>", result);
}
```

FakeHttpContext and FakeViewDataContainer are just the fake implementations of HttpContextBase and IViewDataContainer.

This test passes and returns the expected result. However,  I ‘m not sure I’m correctly utilizing the Autofixture here. Is there a better way to use AutoFixture within this Unit Test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on partial information it's hard to tell exactly how the above test could be further reduced, but I would guess that it could be reduced.

First of all, the combo of invoking `Inject` followed by `CreateAnonymous` is rather idiomatic - particularly if you reverse the sequence. This is called [Freezing](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/03/17/AutoFixtureFreeze.aspx) the anonymous value (and is equivalent to a DI container's Singleton lifetime scope). It can be stated more succinctly like this:

```
var vc = fixture.Freeze<ViewContext>();
```

It also seems as though the test is mapping HttpContext to FakeHttpContext. [Mapping can be done a little bit easier](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/04/06/MappingTypesWithAutoFixture.aspx), but that'll map Transient instances...

In any case, unless you have compelling reasons to use [Manual Mocks instead of a dynamic Mock library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163358.aspx), you might as well decide to use [AutoFixture as an auto-mocking container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/19/AutoFixtureAsAnAutomockingContainer.aspx). That might rid you of a lot of that type mapping.

So, given all that, I'd *guess* that you might be able to reduce the test to something like this:

```
[Fact]
public void SampleTableHtmlHelper_WhenKeyExistWithinHttpContext_ReturnsExpectedHtml()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

    //Arrange
    var vc = fixture.Freeze<ViewContext>();
    vc.HttpContext.Items.Add(Keys.SomeKey, "foo");

    var htmlHelper = fixture.CreateAnonymous<HtmlHelper>();
    var sampleModel = fixture.CreateAnonymous<SampleModel>();

    //Act
    var result = SampleHelpers.SampleTable(htmlHelper, sampleModel, null).ToString();

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal("<table id=\"foo\"></table>", result);
}
```

However, most of the Arrange part is now purely declarative, and since you seem to already be using xUnit.net, you can use [AutoData Theories for AutoFixture](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheoriesWithAutoFixture.aspx) to move most of the variables to method arguments:

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void SampleTableHtmlHelper_WhenKeyExistWithinHttpContext_ReturnsExpectedHtml(
    [Frozen]ViewContext vc,
    HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    SampleModel sampleModel)
{
    //Arrange
    vc.HttpContext.Items.Add(Keys.SomeKey, "foo");

    //Act
    var result = SampleHelpers.SampleTable(htmlHelper, sampleModel, null).ToString();

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal("<table id=\"foo\"></table>", result);
}
```

This assumes that you've bridged the AutoMoqCustomization with the AutoDataAttribute like this:

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute :
        base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization()))
    { }
}
```

Please keep in mind that you may need to tweak the above code a bit to make it fit the details of your API. This is only meant as a sketch.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot Mark.