# Unit testing HtmlHelper extension method fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, html-helper

I am trying to test some `HtmlHelper` extension methods I have written. My first problem was how to create a `HtmlHelper` instance, but I solved that using this code:

```cs
private static HtmlHelper<T> CreateHtmlHelper<T>(T model)
{
    var viewDataDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(model);
    var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(new Mock<HttpContextBase>().Object,
    new RouteData(),
    new Mock<ControllerBase>().Object);

    var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, new Mock<IView>().Object, viewDataDictionary, new TempDataDictionary(), new Mock<TextWriter>().Object);

    var mockViewDataContainer = new Mock<IViewDataContainer>();
mockViewDataContainer.Setup(v => v.ViewData).Returns(viewDataDictionary);

    return new HtmlHelper<T>(viewContext, mockViewDataContainer.Object);
}
```

Several of my tests now work fine, but there is one test that throws an exception. The test is defined as follows:

```cs
// Arrange
var inputDictionary = CreateDictionary();
var htmlHelper = CreateHtmlHelper(inputDictionary);

// Act
var actualHtmlString = htmlHelper.EditorFor(m => m.Dict, model).ToHtmlString();
...
```

The `EditorFor` method is my extension method. Somewhere in that method, the following call is made:

```cs
tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(expression, metadata));
```

It is that when this code is executed from my unit test that the following exception is thrown:

```cs
System.NullReferenceExceptionObject reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext.ScopeCache.Get(IDictionary`2 scope, HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext.get_UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled()
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(String name, ModelMetadata metadata)
   at AspNetMvcDictionarySerialization.HtmlHelperExtensions.InputTagHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, InputType inputType, String expression, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes, String fullName, Int32 index, String fieldType, String val) in HtmlHelperExtensions.cs: line 154
```

So the code fails in `ScopeCache.Get`, but why? Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What I ended up doing was looking at the [source code of ASP.NET MVC](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest). In their code, they also test `HtmlHelper` instances. They do so using a utility class named `MvcHelper`, which provides convenience methods to create new `HtmlHelper` instance with a correctly prepared HTTP context.

After removing the code I did not need, I ended up with the following class:

```cs
public static class MvcHelper
{
    public static HtmlHelper<TModel> GetHtmlHelper<TModel>(TModel inputDictionary)
    {
        var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(inputDictionary);
        var mockViewContext = new Mock<ViewContext> { CallBase = true };
        mockViewContext.Setup(c => c.ViewData).Returns(viewData);
        mockViewContext.Setup(c => c.HttpContext.Items).Returns(new Hashtable());

        return new HtmlHelper<TModel>(mockViewContext.Object, GetViewDataContainer(viewData));
    }

    public static IViewDataContainer GetViewDataContainer(ViewDataDictionary viewData)
    {
        var mockContainer = new Mock<IViewDataContainer>();
        mockContainer.Setup(c => c.ViewData).Returns(viewData);
        return mockContainer.Object;
    }
}
```

With this helper class, my code executed correctly.

I have created a gist for the complete helper class to allow for easy inclusion in your project: https://gist.github.com/ErikSchierboom/6da474dcd5751fbbc94c

Comment: Dude you ROCK. This is the first one that worked to allow me to test some Helper Methods. I need to find a few other StackOverflow questions on mocking an HtmlHelper and say this is the better answer.

Comment: Did anyone get into troubles with that code? I end up with CachedAssociatedMetadataProvider.PrototypeCache throwing an exception :/

Comment: Thank you so much.  I spent an entire day getting `NullReferenceException`s, until I found your post.

Comment: Mocking HttpContext.Items also helps if you get the "The method or operation is not implemented" exception

Answer (score 1):

Looks you probably need to mock the HttpContext too.

Comment: You mean `HttpContext.Current`? Do you have any sample code to do that?