# Unit test using HtmlHelper in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

Although there are tag helpers now, you still need `HtmlHelper` from time to time, e.g., inside your tag helpers. I'm trying to write tests for one of my tag helpers which calls into `HtmlHelper`.

In ASP.NET MVC 5 there have been ways to create an HtmlHelper for testing purposes, e.g., see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216750/1400869

However, the ctor changed extensively in ASP.NET Core.

What is a good way to create an HtmlHelper for testing purposes using ASP.NET Core 1.1?

Comment: Can you abstract your tag helper to use the `IHtmlHelper` interface? That can be injected into the constructor of the tag helper, which makes mocking trivial.

Comment: We want to write integration tests, so I'm looking for a way to really instantiate an HtmlHelper instead of faking it.

Comment: See also https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4843 for more information on how we "solved" the issue.